# Shutting Down or Hibernating Overnight?

Tags: windows-7, power

This question is for the all important reason of winning a bet.

Which of the following is more energy efficient?

1. Leave a Windows 7 computer sleeping overnight
2. Leave a Windows 7 computer hibernating overnight
3. Shut Down a Windows 7 computer and start it in the morning

More importantly, is there a way to measure this?  From a Layman's point of view is seems obvious that number three is the right answer, but when I started thinking about the lower power drawn in a sleep/hibernation state, and the Hard Work™ a computer needs to do when it starts up, I started wondering if this might be one of those counter intuitive things.

Comment: I hope you didn't bet on #1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

You measure it by getting something like a [Kill-A-Watt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009MDBU).

And the answer will be that #2 and #3 are the same, and involve the lowest power levels.

Sleep mode involves keeping parts of the computer powered for a quick restart. Hibrenate involves pushing everything to disk, then doing a full hardware shutdown, so hibernate and shutdown are the same (power-wise), while sleep needs a little bit of power to keep things alive.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between a hibernate and a power-off is that hibernation backs up the contents of RAM to the hard drive first, followed by a power-off.  Both states leave the computer in the lowest-power state possible.

#1 is standby.  It's a lower power state, but it's still using enough power to keep the contents of RAM refreshed, and the CPU is still running in a low-power idle state.

Wven when powered off, the system still consumes a tiny amount of power.

The only truly zero power state is to unplug it.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernating and shutdown the computer should be identical. The difference is as follows:

- **Sleep**: Most of your hardware is powered off, or put into a low power state. The contents of RAM are kept alive through continuos refreshes, which uses some power. This mode is the fastest to wake up from, but not as power saving as the others
- **Hibernate**: The contents of your RAM are written to disk, and your computer is powered off. When you wake it up, it loads your data back into RAM. This saves more power, but takes longer to wake from
- **Off**: From a power consumption point of view, this should be equivalent to hibernation, but you will not be restored to the previous state when you turn the computer back on.

If you want to know how *much* of a difference in power consumption there is between these different modes, you can use a device like Kill-A-Watt (as Michael Kohne wrote in his answer).

Comment: @Izam Wouldn't restarting the computer mean launching a bunch of startup processes for the operating system and applications (expensive processor wise, uses more power), whereas hibernation would skip this since it's just loading a disk image directly into ram?

Comment: @AlanStorm And writing the contents of RAM to disk also uses power. We are talking about *extremely* minuscule amounts of power here though. I *highly* doubt you would be able to find a difference.